# Arrow with incomplete border

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

[image: Arrow with incomplete border]

How to make this arrow on the left side of a white div.
Here is the css that I have tried but it makes only one color border.

```
.white-box{
        padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .white-box:after,white-box:before{
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .white-box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-right-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.white-box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Comment: You need to at least try to code this yourself, then if you're stuck post your code here. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: i tired to code myself

Comment: then show us your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) and a [path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) it is pretty simple:

```css
svg{
  width:30%; height:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="1 0 5 10">
  <path d="M5 3 V1 L2 5 L5 9 V7" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.5" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```